# how to check div tag its empty or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to check div tag its empty or not by using java script?

**HTML**

```
<div class="txt"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    if(txt != null ){
        document.write("There is content in that div");
    }else{
        document.write("There is NO content in that div");
    }
</script>
```

I already tried, but shows always "there is a content in this divtag".

Comment: You need to select the element, and get the content from it.  Check out `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Native Javascript way:

**Check text contents:**

```
var sTextContents = document.getElementsByClassName('txt')[0].textContent;

if (sTextContents != "") {
    //text contents exists
}
```

**Check HTML contents:**

```
var sHTMLContents = document.getElementsByClassName('txt')[0].innerHTML;

if (sHTMLContents != "") {
    //html contents exists
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the innerHTML property of the element, i.e. if the div has id *divid*:

```
    if (document.getElementById('divid').innerHTML != "") {
        ...
    }
```

This is non-jQuery javascript, but should work as well, albeit possibly less aesthetic if used along jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

This will check if there is any textual content:

```
 $('div').text() === ''
```

This will check if there is anything at all, including markup:

```
 $('div').html() === ''
```

Of course, you probably want to specify a specific `div`, this one will act upon every `div` in your document which is certainly not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `html()` to check the contents as

```
var txt = $('div').html();
/* if you just want to use Plain JS then */
var txt = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].innerHTML;
if (txt != null ) {
   document.write("There is content in that div");
} else {
   document.write("There is NO content in that div");
}
```

Otherwise you can replace the `html()` method with `text()` method too. Text won't search for the HTML content, but will search for the text content, such as the content that is shown to the user in the Browser.

Comment: <div class="txt"> <p>hi </p></div>
<script>
var txt = document.getElementsByTagName("div").innerHTML;
if (txt != null ) {
   document.write("There is content in that div");
} else {
   document.write("There is NO content in that div");
}
</script>result:"There is NO content in that div"

Comment: @user1863480 Hi pardon me, you need to write `[0]` too. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/Y9NAg/

Comment: When you add `[0]` this will search for the first div element and will search for its content! :) the result was There is content in that div @user1863480, Good luck ..